# Data doesn't refres after Update or Delete using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, datatable

I'm coding a CRUD system using PHP (with CodeIgniter) AJAX, Datatables, and MySQL. Almost everything is working fine but Update and delete process.

You can update or delete ONE record but if you want to update/delete two or more in a row, you get the following error in the javascript console:

> BlockquoteUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

You're able to delete/update another record after reload all the page.

This is my html code:

```
<form role="form" id="agregarStaffFrm" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label">
            <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" id="c_usuario" name="c_usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario"
                required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
            <div class="valid-feedback">
                Looks good!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" id="c_nombre" name="c_nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre"
                required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label">
            <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" id="c_apellido" name="c_apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido"
                autofocus="autofocus">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="c_password" name="c_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                autofocus="autofocus">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="categoria">Sucursal</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="c_sucursal" name="c_sucursal">
        <?php 
            foreach ($sucursales as $suc)
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$suc['nombre'].'">'.$suc['nombre'].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="agregar btn btn-success" id="agregar_Staff_btn">Aceptar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
```

This is the javascript code to get data from datatables an populate the update form:

```
var editar_staff = function(tbody, table){
    $(tbody).on("click", "button.editar", function(){
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        var id = $("#u_id").val(data.id);
        var nombre = $("#nombre").val(data.Nombre);
        var apellido = $("#apellido").val(data.Apellido);
    });
}
```

This is the code to update (save) the data after user modify them:

```
var guardar = function (){
    $("#staffFrm").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('control/u_cajero')?>",
            data: frm
        }).done(function(info){      
            var json_info = JSON.parse(info);
            $("#staff").modal("hide");
            limpiar_formulario();
            document.getElementById("mensajeAlerta").innerHTML = json_info;
    listar();
        });
    });     
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This line is returning `undefined`:

```
table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
```

The code you've provided doesn't indicate what `table` is or how it's used. However, the error shows that the line above is returning `undefined`. I'd suggest stepping through with a debugger to verify `$(this)` is what you think it is.